# JavaFX: CellValueFactory binding

Tags: javafx

As a continuation of my question [FXML: Bind to nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317083/fxml-bind-to-nested-field/41318249#41318249), I hava multiple columns, and I would like to set their `CellValueFactory` avoiding repetitive code, here is what I tried:

```
public static <T> void BindTableColumn(TableColumn<T, String> column, String fieldName){
    column.setCellValueFactory(data ->{
        String value = "";
        T model = data.getValue();
        if(model == null){
            value = null;
        }else{
            try {
                value = model.getClass().getField(fieldName).get(new String()).toString();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException
                    | SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new SimpleStringProperty(value);
    });
}
```

But my fields are `private` so is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the name of the field as a `String`, pass a function retrieving it:

```
public static <T> void bindTableColumn(TableColumn<T, String> column, Function<T,String> field){
    column.setCellValueFactory(data ->{
        String value ;
        T model = data.getValue();
        if(model == null){
            value = null;
        }else{
            value = field.apply(model);
        }
        return new SimpleStringProperty(value);
    });
}
```

and then invoke it with something like

```
TableColumn<Item, String> nameColumn = ... ;

bindTableColumn(nameColumn, Item::getName);
```